Using Google OR-Tools with SCIP solver in x86 solution
I made a proof-of-concept application using Google OR-Tools with SCIP solver and it worked perfectly for my problem. But when I added OR-Tools to my actual solution (which uses .NET Framework 4.6.2), I had a problem: my projects use x86 architecture due to compatibility with some other libraries, but the latest versions of OR-Tools (v9.11 as of now) use x64 architecture.
I installed Google.OrTools.x86 from nuget package manager, and its latest version is 5.0.6170.2. But when I try to create SCIP solver, I get a null value; I suppose this version does not support SCIP solver.
Did I do something wrong? Is there a x86 version that supports SCIP solver? If not, is there a way to use a x64 version of OR-Tools in my x86 solution?

We dropped support for 32bit but years ago.
Use scip directly.
